# Pyinstaller - Include empty folder in dist

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I'm trying to build a python script that needs a specific directory to create some files into. When I try to build the application using "PyInstaller" it doesn't include this empty *"reports"* folder in the dist. All the other folders that have files in them are included as normal. Note that I'm not using the `--onefile` command and the executable itself is located inside the folder: `dist/main/main.exe`

My main.spec file

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-

block_cipher = None

added_files = [
         ( 'database/reports.sqlite', 'database' ),
         ( 'templates/*', 'templates' ),
         ( 'reports', 'reports' )
         ]

a = Analysis(['main.py'],
             pathex=['\\\\SRV\\Data\\pyi'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=added_files,
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='main',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=False )
coll = COLLECT(exe,
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               strip=False,
               upx=True,
               upx_exclude=[],
               name='main')
```

Comment: You are trying to save files on runtime into the executable? I don't believe that is possible. Instead, perhaps you should make a folder in the executable's dir, and save files in there, or look for the standard directory to save applications files into (OSX/Win).

Comment: If I create the folder inside the dist directory everything is working fine and the files produced by the executable are saved in there just as they should. The problem is that this folder is not created upon the building of the executable. Note that I'm not using the --onefile command so the executable is included in a directory.

Comment: Have ever found a solution to this?

Comment: Please make sure, if the directory that has the code and you want to include has the __init__.py file inside it, thus, it can be recognised as a package directory, or you can add additional folders into your directory by modifying .spec file generated by running pyinstaller first time, and then run pyinstaller again.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue as yours and I managed to "copy" a folder to the output using the *--add-data* option provided by PyInstaller.

Note, I tested this command on a Windows 10 machine using the version 5.7.0 of PyInstaller:

```
py -m PyInstaller --add-data "Logs;Logs" .\main.py
```

On Linux or other OS this should work:

```
pyinstaller --add-data "Logs:Logs" ./main.py
```

Where "Logs" was a folder in the root of the application, where the "main.py" file was located in.

As stated in the [documentation](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/usage.html#cmdoption-add-data), the option value should be in the form **"SOURCE;DESTINATION"** on Windows and **"SOURCE:DESTINATION"** on most Unix systems. The source could be both a file (e.g. example.json) or a folder. The destination is the realtive path in the "dist" folder where to copy the source ("." to put a file in the root of the dist folder).

Hope this helps someone else! :)